# Silverlight MergedDictionaries and subclassing of Application

Tags: silverlight

We have subclassed the Silverlight Application class to add some additional functionality and then use this in multiple projects. The problem is that the Resources defined in App.xaml do not seem to get loaded. Has anyone else seen this and/or have some insight? Here are the contents of App.xaml (note: the application starts and runs fine but then chokes when it looks for a Resource)

```
<myNS:ApplicationBase 
 xmlns:myNS="clr-namespace:Corp.XYZ.Infrastructure.Silverlight.Core;assembly=Corp.XYZ.Infrastructure.Silverlight.Core" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         x:Class="Corp.XYZ.BMW.App"
         >
<myNS:ApplicationBase.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary   Source="Resources/AlternateControlStyles/StandardExpander.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</myNS:ApplicationBase.Resources>
```

Comment: You re-use the source code in multiple projects?  Or you have built a library containing this class and reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it..... was not doing an InitializeComponent() in derived constructor...duh :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the build action for StandardExpander.xaml?  It should be Page (the default when you add a resourcedictionary).